# Разделить строку на слова и вывести их на печать по одному

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать программу, используя функцию. Вводишь строку из несколько слов с пробелами. Находишь все слова и выводишь все слова отдельными строчками. Что я делаю не так?

```
str1 = str(input())
i = 0
k = 0
list = []

def space(str1):
 return(str1)
 while k <= len(str1):
  if str1(i) != " ":
   list.append(str(i))
   return(list)
  i += 1
  k += 1

mini_list = space(str1)
print(mini_list)
```

Comment: Решение задачки двумя строчками `for line in input().split(' '):print(line)` :D

Comment: @gil9red опубликуйте ответ что ли. Только расскажите, что в коде происходит )

Comment: @gil9red кстати, умею одной: `[print(line) for line in input().split()]`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не надо такой код публиковать там, где его могут увидеть начинающие. Или хотя бы упоминайте, что использование сайд-эффектов в списковых включениях - это моветон, и в реальном коде такого делать не стоит.

Comment: @Александр стыдно, но спрошу: а что такое списковые включения? Конструкцию `[f(x) for x in iterable]` я знаю под именем "генератор". (А так-то вы правы, такой код — исключительно для развлечения)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это выражения вида [f(x) for x in seq]. Их хорошим использованием является только генерация списков, без вывода вовне и без изменения внешних переменных.

Comment: @Александр ага, спасибо, значит я просто не знаком с русскоязычным термином.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: стыднее не спрашивать. Слово *генератор* для ленивых конструкций таких как genexpr: `squares = (x*x for x in iterable)` лучше использовать. listcomp (списковое включение) возвращает список и на уровне байткода также [генератор не использует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567735/23044) Я видел переводы "генератор списков" для listcomp, что не точно по реализации и [иногда имеет другой смысл в функциональном программировании](https://goo.gl/oPGgqd).

Comment: @jfs спасибо, стало понятнее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Находишь все слова

Зря вы перебираете строку посимвольно в поисках пробелов.

- Во-первых, бывают и другие пробельные символы, например, неразрывный пробел или табуляция. Они тоже разделяют строку на слова.
- Во-вторых, для деления строки на слова в Python 3 есть метод [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Он разбивает строку по заданному разделителю, а если не указывать разделитель (т.е. по умолчанию) — по пробельным символам (конкретно: space, tab, newline, return, formfeed). Возвращает список строк, на которые поделил исходную.

Вот так:

```
words = input().split()
```

Заметьте, что `str(input())` не нужно, `input()` и так возвращает строку.

Чтобы вывести каждое слово, достаточно перебрать список и каждое напечатать.

```
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Оба действия можно объединить для лаконичности:

```
for word in input().split():
    print(word)
```

Comment: input() - плохая функция. Она интерпретирует строку.
Надо использовать raw_input()

Comment: @NickolayMerkin вопрос о [tag:python3], а в нём, насколько я знаю, [`input` это тот же `raw_input` из второго](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Ошибаюсь?

Comment: нерекомендуемо, но возможно: `print(*input().split(), sep='\n')`

Comment: @jfs каждый раз приятно удивляюсь использованию этого синтаксиса. )

Answer (score 4):

Как сказал **Igor Sergeevich** можно воспользоватся стандартным методом для работы со строками. Но так как я вижу что вы пытаетесь сделать это в ручную, предложу такой вариант:

```
In [15]: def foo(string):
    ...:     Flag = False
    ...:     for i in string:
    ...:         if i != ' ':
    ...:             if Flag:
    ...:                 print()
    ...:             print(i, end='')
    ...:             Flag = False
    ...:         else:
    ...:             Flag = True
```

Использование:

```
In [18]: foo('string for example')
```

Результат:

```
string
for
example
```

Comment: @NickVolynkin я восстановил и поправил, теперь работает на любом кол-ве пробелов :)

Comment: Обещанный плюс. Кстати, а зачем с большой буквы `Flag`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да как-то автоматично..

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
list(map(print, input().split(' ')))
```

Comment: Тоже круто, но автор вопроса не поймет функциональщину без объяснений, явно же новичок. :)

Answer (score 4):

Вот так можно:

```
single_line = raw_input()

# разбить по пробелам, склеить обратно по LFам
words_in_lines = '\n'.join(single_line.split())
# если между словами ровно по одному пробелу
words_in_lines = single_line.replace(' ', '\n')
# если там серии пробелов
words_in_lines = re.sub(r'\s+', '\n', single_line)

print words_in_lines
```

Comment: Судя по принтам, у вас Python2, а у автора вопроса — Python3.  А замена через регулярку — хитро )

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать значительно проще, пользуясь методами работы со строками:

```
new_list = my_str.split(' ')
```

А ваша не работает из-за `return` перед циклом, интерпретатор прекращает выполнять функцию, возвращает ответ и не входит в цикл, `return` надо переместить в конц функции.

Answer (score 2):

Также можно обратиться к регуляркам:

```
import re

text = input()  # "1 2   4         555"

for x in re.split(r'\s+', text):
    print(x)
```

Консоль:

```
1
2
4
555
```