# Когда в коде есть пробелы он не работает

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Есть дс бот который должен при сообщении проверять есть ли в сообщении запрещеные слова, но когда в сообщении стоит пробел он ложно срабатывает, вот сам код:

```
blacklist = ["test1","test2"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
    msgid = ctx.message.id
    msgc = await ctx.fetch_message(msgid) 
    msg = msgc.content
    author = ctx.author
    author_roles = author.roles
    if str(author.id) == "856512828785426472":
        pass
    else:
        if "966009778792960120" in str(author.roles):
            for word in str(msg):
                if str(word) in str(blacklist):
                    await ctx.send("5.4  нарушаешь?")
                    break
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите [mcve], который будет возможно запустить и который продемонстрирует ложное срабатывание

Comment: Ну а вообще вы зачем-то пытаетесь перебрать в цикле каждый символ сообщения (ваша переменная `word` — это не слово, а один символ)

Comment: Обновлённый код не является минимальным воспроизводимым примером, его невзоможно запустить. Впрочем, это не отменяет того, что `word` это не слово, а один символ

Comment: А как задать в переменную word слово

Comment: [Разделить строку на слова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673692)

Comment: Да и этот код исправно работает не считая то что тригериться на пробелы

Comment: Кроме того, вы зачем-то преобразовываете список `blacklist` в строку (зачем?) — и в итоге получается строка `['test1', 'test2']` — и в ней есть пробел. Когда переменная `word` становится символом пробела, выполняется проверка на наличие пробела в этой строке — а так как пробел в ней действительно есть, то условие успешно срабатывает. То же самое касается не только пробела, но и любых других символов (`1`, `2`, `e`, `s`, `t`)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте **split** что бы получить все слова из сообщения в качестве списка и по нему уже проверять.

```
blacklist = ['test', 'bad']

msg = 'some message with bad words'

for word in msg.split():
    # msg.split() вернет ['some', 'message', 'with', 'bad', 'words']
    if word in blacklist:
        print('Bad word!')
        break
```