# Можно ли улучшить поиск в многомерном списке python

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск, списки

Здравствуйте. Есть многомерный список:

```
spisok=[{'a':'1','b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]
```

необходимо проверить есть ли в списке ключ 'a' с определенным значением.
поискав в интернете смог собрать такую конструкцию:

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    if spisok[i]['a'] == stroka_poiska:
        print('True')
```

Можно ли как то улучшить данный код? И верна ли логика построения алгоритма?

Comment: лучше явно это **списком словарей** назвать, а не многомерным списком (последнее более применимо, когда дочерний контейнер также списком является, к примеру: `matrix = [[0]*10 for _ in range(5)]` или [массив] `a = numpy.arange(12).reshape((3,4))`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def chk_for_val(lst, key, val):
    for d in lst:
        if d.get(key) == val:
            return True
    return False
```

При использовании `dict.get(key)` (вместо `dict[key]`) - не будут генерироваться исключения для несуществующих ключей

```
In [138]: chk_for_val(lst, 'a', '3')
Out[138]: True

In [139]: chk_for_val(lst, 'X', '3')
Out[139]: False
```

Comment: а почему `d.get(key)`, а не `d[key]`?

Comment: @gil9red, как раз писал это в ответ пока вы писали комментарий ;)

Comment: да действительно такой вариант "if d.get(key) == val:" корректнее отрабатывает если нет ключа для поиска. в таком случае не прерывается выполнение всего скрипта

Comment: any() без необходимости лучше не переопределять

Answer (score 6):

Самый лучший вариант:

```
check = any(dct.get('a')==stroka_poiska
            for dct in spisok)

print(check)
```

Лаконично, читабельно и эффективно.

Comment: главное что код читаемый здесь. Что эффективней, не стоит без [измерений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567735/23044) заявлять. Хотя пока вам profiler не сказал обратного, любой линейный алгоритм подходит здесь (можно не думать о производительности).

Answer (score 2):

Предложу свой немного странноватый вариант:

```
In [17]: array = [{'a':'1','b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]

In [18]: def search(dictionary, key, value):
    ...:     verbose_data = sum(map(list, map(dict.items, dictionary)), [])
    ...:     return (key, value) in verbose_data
    ...:

In [19]: search(array, 'a', '1')
Out[19]: True

In [20]: search(array, 'a', '4')
Out[20]: False
```

Или:

```
In [27]: search = lambda array, key, value: any(map(lambda x: (key, value) in x.items(), array))

In [28]: search(array, 'a', '1')
Out[28]: True

In [29]: search(array, 'A', '1')
Out[29]: False
```

Или:

```
In [13]: from itertools import takewhile

In [14]: def search(array, key, value):
    ...:     return len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x.get(key) != value, array))) < len(array)
    ...:

In [15]: search(array, 'a', '3')
Out[15]: True

In [16]: search(array, 'A', '3')
Out[16]: False
```

Comment: ужасы. Похоже вы пытаетесь, что-то вроде: `(key, value) in chain(*map(dict.items, list_of_dicts))` выразить (itertools) в качестве альтернативы для `any(d.get(key)==value for d in list_of_dicts)` (последнее более предпочтительно).

Comment: @jfs поэтому они и странноваты)

Answer (score 1):

В стандартной библиотеке collections есть класс отображения ChainMap. Он хранит  список отображений, так что их можно просматривать как единое целое.

Поиск производится в каждом отображении по порядку и завершается успешно, если ключ найден хотя бы в одном.

```
from collections import ChainMap
spisok=[{'a':'1','b':'2'},{'a':'3','b':'4'}]

chain = ChainMap(*spisok)

print(chain.get('a'))
```

[документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)

Comment: Как это отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: верно, не решает. спасибо. почему то прозевал ключевой момент (ключ 'a' с определенным значением)

Answer (score -1):

Я вот так сделал:

```
for i in range(len(spisok)):
    for key in spisok[i]:
        if spisok[i][key]=='4':
            print(spisok[i][key])
```