# Написание цикла for и if в одну строку

Tags: python, циклы

В простом варианте цикл for и команда if занимают минимум три строки и два отступа. Если записывать их в одну строку - это ускоряет работу программы? Или только дает более читабельную форму и уменьшает кол-во строк, но практической пользы нет?
PS мой код никто больше не читает)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Почему один способ проверки чисел в списке медленнее второго?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567735/23044)

Comment: Спасибо, полезная ссылочка @jfs

Answer (score 3):

На больших объемах данных [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) обычно работает быстрее простого `for ... loop`:

пример для списка с 10.000.000 элементов:

```
In [51]: lst = list(range(10**7))

In [52]: %%timeit
    ...: res = []
    ...: for x in lst:
    ...:     if x % 3 == 0:
    ...:         res.append(x)
    ...:
2.26 s ± 55.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [53]: %%timeit
    ...: res = [x for x in lst if x % 3 == 0]
    ...:
1.66 s ± 6.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: как можно изменить ваш код, чтобы запустить его в jupyter notebook? И в чем Вы его запускали?

Comment: Я усиленно пробовал разобраться в статье от первого коментатора, хотел понять почему у генераторов быстрее время работы со списком чем через цикл фор. Но так и не понял. пока мой уровень знаний не позволяет. Не могли бы Вы объяснить очень на пальцах в чем идея такого выигрыша?

Comment: @AlexSapsay, я запускал весь код в iPython (интерактивный Python - консольный аналог Jupyter). “In [XX] “ - это “prompt” , его запускать не надо

Comment: @AlexSapsay, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list) неплохое сравнение

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. Если я правильно понял, то list comprehension выигрывает в скорости за счет оптимизации байт кода, при работе со списками. В операциях append and pop

Comment: можно @MaxU ли считать генераторы списков= list comprehension?

Comment: @AlexSapsay, нет, это не одно и тоже. [Здесь более подробно о различиях...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: спасибо, за ссылку и ответ