# Что быстрее работает в питоне: list(filter(lambda или соответствующее listcomp?

Tags: python, производительность, lambda

В общем такой вопрос. Что быстрее lamda функции и filter или же генераторы? Для примера такой код.

```
list(filter(lambda pr: projectsIds.get(pr['id'], 0), projects))
[pr for pr in projects if projectsIds.get(pr['id'], 0)]
```

Если правильно верить интернету то генераторы быстрее, но мало ли что я упустил.

Comment: Возьмите и измерьте :)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Почему один способ проверки чисел в списке медленнее второго?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567735/23044)

Answer (score 6):

Генератор списка быстрее.

Автор не указывал входные данные, поэтому придумал свои.

После используя модуль `timeit` замерил скорость:

```
from timeit import timeit

projects_ids = {i: 0 if i % 2 == 0 else 1 for i in range(100)}
projects = [{'id': i, 'name': hex(i)} for i in range(1000)]

NUMBER = 1000
global_vars = {'projects_ids': projects_ids, 'projects': projects}

stmt_1 = "list(filter(lambda pr: projects_ids.get(pr['id'], 0), projects))"
print(timeit(stmt_1, globals=global_vars, number=NUMBER))

stmt_2 = "[pr for pr in projects if projects_ids.get(pr['id'], 0)]"
print(timeit(stmt_2, globals=global_vars, number=NUMBER))
```

Результат:

```
0.164726723
0.094391803
```

Answer (score 5):

Как всегда: *"It depends."* `list(filter` может быть быстрее и медленнее чем listcomp:

```
In: %timeit list(filter(lambda x: x, range(1000)))
Out:    136 µs ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In: %timeit [x for x in range(1000) if x]
Out:    51.6 µs ± 537 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In: %timeit list(filter(bool, range(1000)))
Out:    27.7 µs ± 222 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

`lambda` вариант самый медленный, `if x` вариант быстрее, вариант с явной именованной функции `bool` и `filter` быстрее всех здесь (`filter(None` —  похожее время). Все варианты одинаковый результат возвращают.

Если ваш profiler не говорит, что выражение с listcomp или filter является узким местом в вашем коде, то используйте самый читаемый вариант: если у вас есть именованная функция (к примеру: `odd(n)`), то вариант с `filter(odd, numbers)` выглядит чище, если у вас просто безымянное выражение в качестве условия, то вариант с genexpr/listcomp более подходящий.